# Android: Moving window of items in a ListView?

Tags: android, http, listview, user-interface, rss

I am trying to update the ListView with periodic updates taken from an HTTP response. Now, I am thinking that because this is very specific to my application, I can get away by using a background thread and then updating the ListView using the magic UI thread. The last time I tried this, I had to remove the entire adapter of the ListView and then fill it up again so it  worked. But this time, what I am trying to do is a more "smooth" scrolling ListView... something like a scrolling ticker... Is there a different approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on the `Adapter`. If you are using an `ArrayAdapter`, you can call `add()` on the `ArrayAdapter` itself to add items on the fly.

Comment: Thank You. So the problem is, I am able to get it to update but the listview doesn't seem to get updated unless I scroll through it after which it starts getting elements from the newly filled adapter. Any suggestions?

Comment: Visit http://commonsware.com/Android, scroll down, and click on the Source Code link to download a ZIP file. In there, look for the Threads/Asyncer project. There, you will find an example of a ListView being updated from a background thread. Those updates are displayed in real time (at least the scrollbar is shrinking, showing that the ListView knows about the new rows). See if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for help... I will look into that... From what you described, I think that is what I am looking for...